# Javascript Splice is splicing remained values when looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice

```
var array = [
    ["0","1","2","3","4","5"],
    ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
];
 
angular.forEach(array, function(nestedArray){ 
    angular.forEach(nextedArray, function(value){
        console.log(value);
        nextedArray.splice(0,3);
    });
});
console.log(count);
```

**Desired output**

> > 0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5

**But I am getting output of**

> > 0,1,2,0,1,2

Each inside array has 6 values, when I loop the inside array, I cut 3 items, then I expect to loop again as there are 3 items remained but it just gets out of the loop. When I add 7 items in each array, it's looping after removing 3 items.
When I debug the code, after splicing from index 0,1,2 then I still have '3,4,5' to loop 3 times more in the nested loop right?

Comment: It's never a good idea to remove items from an array while looping it

Comment: What is the desired output? The question is nor very clear

Comment: `... after splicing from index 0,1,2 then it a` ??? a what? You forgot to finish the description.

Comment: Your parameter is `nestedArray` but you are using `nextedArray`